# iptables-save behaviour in network namespace in linux

Tags: linux, iptables, network-namespaces

My setup:

- Linux 4.16.13-2-ARCH
- iproute2 4.16.0-1
- iptables 1.6.2-2

**Issue:**
Output of iptables-save is empty inside network namespace. If iptables -L called before, iptables-save provides correct output.

NOK case can be reproduced in following way: (output is empty)

```
ip netns add 123 && ip netns exec 123 iptables-save && ip netns del 123
```

OK case is reproduced in following way:

```
ip netns add 123 && ip netns exec 123 iptables -L &>/dev/null && ip netns exec 123 iptables-save && ip netns del 123
```

And provides default iptables config:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.2 on Tue Jun 12 10:41:10 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 12 10:41:10 2018
```

Why do I need to call **iptables -L** to have it working ?

Comment: well, why isn't there the raw entry? or the nat entry? or the mangle entry? which could all exist on the host. Because they weren't used either. They are not activated until used. iptables-save won't activate them, iptables -L will. Since I have no exact reference about this, I leave it as a comment